# Local Contrast Enhancement for Digit Recognition with cv2 / pytesseract

Tags: python, ocr, opencv, python-tesseract

I want to use pytesseract to read digits from images. The images look as follows:

[image]

[image]

The digits are dotted and in order to be able to use pytesseract, I need **black connected digits on a white background**. To do so, I thought about using **erode** and **dilate** as preprocessing techniques. As you can see, the images are similar, yet quite different in certain aspects. For example, the dots in the first image are darker than the background, while the dots in the second are whiter. That means, in the first image I can use erode to get black connected lines and in the second image I can use dilate to get white connected lines and then inverse the colors. This leads to the following results:

[image]

[image]

Using an appropriate threshold, the first image can easily be read with pytesseract. The second image, whoever, is more tricky. The problem is, that for example parts of the "4" are darker than the background around the three. So a simple threshold is not going to work. I need something like local threshold or local contrast enhancement. Does anybody have an idea here?

Edit:

OTSU, mean threshold and gaussian threshold lead to the following results:

[image]

Comment: have you tried an OTSU threshold yet?

Comment: thanks for the idea, I tried it just now and it doesn't seem to work. I also tried gaussian threshold and mean threshold, but they don't work as intended

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your images are pretty low res, but you can try a method called *gain division*. The idea is that you try to build a model of the background and then weight each input pixel by that model. The output gain should be relatively constant during most of the image.

After gain division is performed, you can try to improve the image by applying an **area filter** and **morphology**. I only tried your first image, because it is the "least worst".

These are the steps to get the *gain-divided* image:

1. Apply a soft **median blur** filter to get rid of high frequency noise.
2. Get the model of the background via **local maximum**. Apply a very strong `close` operation, with a big `structuring element` (I’m using a rectangular kernel of size `15`).
3. Perform **gain adjustment** by dividing `255` between each local maximum pixel. Weight this value with each input image pixel.
4. You should get a nice image where the background illumination is pretty much **normalized**, `threshold` this image to get a binary mask of the characters.

Now, you can improve the quality of the image with the following, additional steps:

1. `Threshold` via **Otsu**, but add a **little bit of bias**. (This, unfortunately, is a  manual step depending on the input).
2. Apply an **area filter** to filter out the smaller blobs of noise.

Let's see the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# image path
path = "C:/opencvImages/"
fileName = "iA904.png"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path+fileName)

# Remove small noise via median:
filterSize = 5
imageMedian = cv2.medianBlur(inputImage, filterSize)

# Get local maximum:
kernelSize = 15
maxKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernelSize, kernelSize))
localMax = cv2.morphologyEx(imageMedian, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, maxKernel, None, None, 1, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)

# Perform gain division
gainDivision = np.where(localMax == 0, 0, (inputImage/localMax))

# Clip the values to [0,255]
gainDivision = np.clip((255 * gainDivision), 0, 255)

# Convert the mat type from float to uint8:
gainDivision = gainDivision.astype("uint8") 

# Convert RGB to grayscale:
grayscaleImage = cv2.cvtColor(gainDivision, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

This is what gain division gets you:

[image]

Note that the lighting is more balanced. Now, let's apply a little bit of contrast enhancement:

```
# Contrast Enhancement:
grayscaleImage = np.uint8(cv2.normalize(grayscaleImage, grayscaleImage, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX))
```

You get this, which creates a little bit more contrast between the foreground and the background:

[image]

Now, let's try to threshold this image to get a nice, binary mask. As I suggested, try Otsu's thresholding but add (or subtract) a little bit of bias to the result. This step, as mentioned, is dependent on the quality of your input:

```
# Threshold via Otsu + bias adjustment:
threshValue, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayscaleImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

threshValue = 0.9 * threshValue
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayscaleImage, threshValue, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

You end up with this binary mask:

[image]

Invert this and filter out the small blobs. I set an `area` threshold value of `10` pixels:

```
# Invert image:
binaryImage = 255 - binaryImage

# Perform an area filter on the binary blobs:
componentsNumber, labeledImage, componentStats, componentCentroids = \
cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(binaryImage, connectivity=4)

# Set the minimum pixels for the area filter:
minArea = 10

# Get the indices/labels of the remaining components based on the area stat
# (skip the background component at index 0)
remainingComponentLabels = [i for i in range(1, componentsNumber) if componentStats[i][4] >= minArea]

# Filter the labeled pixels based on the remaining labels,
# assign pixel intensity to 255 (uint8) for the remaining pixels
filteredImage = np.where(np.isin(labeledImage, remainingComponentLabels) == True, 255, 0).astype("uint8")
```

And this is the final binary mask:

[image]

If you plan on sending this image to an `OCR`, you might want to apply some **morphology** first. Maybe a `closing` to try and join the dots that make up the characters. Also be sure to train your `OCR` classifier with a font that is **close** to what you are actually trying to recognize. This is the (inverted) mask after a size `3` `rectangular` `closing` operation with `3` iterations:

[image]

Edit:

To get the last image, process the filtered output as follows:

```
# Set kernel (structuring element) size:
kernelSize = 3

# Set operation iterations:
opIterations = 3

# Get the structuring element:
maxKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernelSize, kernelSize))

# Perform closing:
closingImage = cv2.morphologyEx(filteredImage, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, maxKernel, None, None, opIterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)

# Invert image to obtain black numbers on white background:
closingImage = 255 - closingImage
```

Comment: amazing answer! Thanks a lot, I will definitely try out all the things you have suggested :)

Comment: @spadel Glad I could help, my friend!

Comment: I am somehow unable to reproduce the last step (closing operation). I tried the following:

`kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(3,3))
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(filteredImage, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)`

But it has no effect. I tried applying on the filtered binary image and its inverse.

Comment: @spadel Check my edit, I added the code to get the last image.